# php/mysql/xampp can't connect to MySQL server on 110

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, xampp

A bit of an oddity:

**Server A**: Windows 8 VPS, XAMPP running PHP and MySQL only, firewall extensively off, all ports open to incoming and outgoing.

**Server B**: Windows 7 my PC, XAMPP running PHP only, firewall off.

**Server C**: Dedicated Linux 3.8 server, standard cPanel installation.

I can't connect to MySQL on server **A** from server **C** using PHP mysqli meanwhile I can connect from server **B** just fine. All permissions are granted to both servers **B** and **C** including ip, host, and % wildcard. Basically, from my PC I can connect to the VPS just fine but from the dedicated linux server it's giving "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_ADDRESS' (110)" error. All 3 servers are on entirely different networks. I'm using the same PHP file to connect on both machines.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would recheck thoroughly the permissions of C on A server.

Comment: Was my first thought and I checked it many times but went ahead and gave it another crack and ended with the same results. Here's the permissions. Server C IP = 192.95.30.192

CREATE USER 'thuser'@'192.95.30.192' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thuser'@'192.95.30.192' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'thuser'@'ns4007837.ip-192-95-30.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thuser'@'ns4007837.ip-192-95-30.net' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'thuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'thuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Honestly, I've even added the name server/s.

Comment: here's a post that might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/91482/how-to-setup-a-mysql-server-to-accept-remote-connections

Comment: At your place I wouldn't IPs too

Comment: So I gave the bind a crack and same result. Also, just ran another test that's twisting my noodle even further. I uploaded the same php file to another server (Server D: basic shared hosting with cPanel - hostgator I thinkg) and it's working fine. Interesting bit is that I didn't add grant permissions for the server D IP. The MySQL is being accessed solely by % wildcard. This makes me think that it can't be some sort of a host resolve issue...

Comment: Yeah maybe it is a host resolve, or for some reason the IP of server C is blocked on server A. I think you should get a server admin look at the issue before something bad happens :)